# How to edit a record in an SQL database from a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to preface this by saying that I am a complete and utter beginner to ASP.Net MVC programming. As such, I would appreciate explanations in a simple manner if possible, as I have very limited experience with this. I have a SQL database, with a table named `AtmAccounts`, in which I have stored some records (the only relevant column here being `AccountBalance`).

As part of my website, I have a ViewModel called `AtmAccountsVM`, defined below:

```
public class AtmAccountVM
{
    public List<AtmAccount> AtmAccountList { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string DepositAmount { get; set; }
    public string WithdrawAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a view, `Deposit`. This view contains a textbox in which the user can enter an amount to deposit into their account, shown below.

```
@using ATMApplication.ViewModels
@model ATMApplication.ViewModels.AtmAccountVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deposit";
 }

<h2>Deposit</h2>

<p>Please input the amount you would like to deposit:</p>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
   @Html.Label("Amount:")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DepositAmount)
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model.AtmAccountList)
    {
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.AtmAccountList.First().AccountBalance)

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountBalance)

    }

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Deposit" class="btn btn-default" />

</div>
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AtmAccountsController : Controller
{
    private BankDBEntities db = new BankDBEntities();

    // GET: AtmAccounts
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ViewModels.AtmAccountVM atmVm = new ViewModels.AtmAccountVM();
              atmVm.AtmAccountList = db.AtmAccounts.Where(a=>a.UserId==userID).ToList();
        atmVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        return View(atmVm);
    }

    // GET: AtmAccounts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.AccTypeId = new SelectList(db.AccTypes, "Id", "AccountType");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: AtmAccounts/Create  
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,AccountNumber,AccountBalance,AccTypeId")] AtmAccount atmAccount)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            atmAccount.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.AtmAccounts.Add(atmAccount);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AccTypeId = new SelectList(db.AccTypes, "Id", "AccountType", atmAccount.AccTypeId);
        return View(atmAccount);
    }

    //Get: Deposit
    public ActionResult Deposit()
    {
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ViewModels.AtmAccountVM atmVm = new ViewModels.AtmAccountVM();
        atmVm.AtmAccountList = db.AtmAccounts.Where(a => a.UserId == userID).ToList();
        atmVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();

        return View(atmVm);
    }
}
```

With this, I am using the ViewModel above to display the `AccountBalance` value - I then want to update this value permanently in the SQL database through user input. How do I do this? Or am I going about this in the completely incorrect way?

UPDATE: New Post Method, flagging an error that reads"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code"

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit(decimal DepositAmount, AtmAccount atmAccount)
    {


        using (var ctx = new BankDBEntities())
        {

            var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ViewModels.AtmAccountVM atmVm = new ViewModels.AtmAccountVM();
            DepositAmount = atmVm.DepositAmount;
            atmVm.AtmAccountList = db.AtmAccounts.Where(a => a.UserId == userID).ToList();
            atmVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();

            if (atmAccount.UserId == atmVm.UserName)
            {
                atmAccount.AccountBalance = atmAccount.AccountBalance + DepositAmount;
            }

            using (var dbCtx = new BankDBEntities())
            {
                dbCtx.Entry(atmAccount).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                dbCtx.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: What do you have in your controller that handles Post right now? Is your <form> tag in a parent view?

Comment: I've added my controller to the question

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using - `mysql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, `sqlite` etc..... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the input element(s) inside a form and you can have an action method to handle the form submit.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Deposit","Account"))
{
 <div class="form-group">
    <div> @Html.Label("Amount:") </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DepositAmount)  </div>
</div>  
  <input type="submit" value="Deposit" class="btn btn-default" />

}
```

Assuming there is a `Deposit` action method in your `AccountController` to handle the form submit

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Deposit(decimal DepositAmount)
{
  // to do  : use the value and return something
}
```

Comment: I have updated the post to include my controller. I have a Get method for my Deposit, but not a Post at current.

Just to clarify, for this solution, I need to change the code in my Deposit View to the above, and then add a post method into my controller? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: yes. that is correct. Also i suggest to switch from `string` to a numeric type for the `DepositAmount` property

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and see where it gets me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, bit of confusion. In my post method in my controller, I'm unclear how to actually update the record in the table, AtmAccounts.AccountBalance. 

Any assistance with this would really be appreciated. I'm sorry for being such a noob at this haha

Comment: you need to read the data from your database, update the property values as needed and save back. If you are using EF, search for "Entity frame work update data". There are tons of samples on the internet

Comment: your method should return some thing if the return type is not void (Ex : return View() or return RedirectToAction)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Another issue now though (I will post the code in the question. When I now attempt to post the new data, I get an error that reads 
"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code"